Get software list from the Azure DevOps CI pipeline using Microsoft SBOM
We have SBOM integrated in our Azure DevOps CI pipeline. The purpose was to get the list of softwares and versions (eg. Node.js, .NET Core etc.) used by the application. Though SBOM generated a json with over 65K+ lines mostly listing all the angular packages. Our purpose is to get only the list of software and versions mentioned at high level in the CI pipeline (Screenshot attached).

Researched over Internet but couldn't find something relevant.
